# Map in Kolin: returning the value of a map when it is a Class

Tags: kotlin

I have the following:

```
list = listOf(
      Class(Event.TYPE1, Class2(State.A, State.b),
      Class(Event.TYPE2, Class2(State.C, State.D)))
```

I have converted to a map:

```
val map = = list.map { it.eventTrigger to it.transaction }.toMap()
```

I am trying return the value of such map (Class2) when they key is and Event enum, as follows:

```
fun hasKeyAValue(
    event: Event,
    transaction: Class2
  ): Boolean = map[event]?.contains(transaction) ?: false
```

Is it even possible to treat a Class as a value? contains would not work in fact work. I have tried to create custom contains method, but with no luck. Ay idea?

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Class2 is a transaction, i would like to validate that a certain Event.TYPE (the key) and its value (Class2) are a valid match

Comment: `fun hasMapping(key: Event, value: Class2) = map[event] == value`

Comment: thanks, but when I test it with valid transactions, I am always getting false values and I am not really sure why.

Comment: The mapping is actually successful (so it looks from debugging it), however it consistently returns false. Inspecting the map I see the following:

```Event.TYPE1=Class2@78dfd8e8```

would that be the reason why the validation fails?

Comment: Did you implement the equals method in `Class2`? `==` translates to `.equals` so it's important you do. Otherwise `==` acts like `===` and will only return true if both objects are the same instance.

Comment: that was it, silly me! Thank you for pointing that out!